# Meaning of terms in SQL Server execution plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, execution-plan, query-performance

I am finding difficulty in understanding the output of execution plan. Execution plan consist of terms like "Estimated sub tree cost", "Estimated I/O cost" etc. I can find the definition of those on net, but not detailed explanation. Can anyone help me to understand what is "Estimated sub tree cost" with an example ?

Also by looking at what factor in execution plan I can say that my query needs to be optimized ?

Please help me.

Comment: I think this is a good place to start http://www.red-gate.com/library/sql-server-execution-plans-2nd-edition

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.11.sqlquery.aspx

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9982/how-do-i-read-query-cost-and-is-it-always-a-percentage

Answer (score 2):

1. `Estimated sub tree cost` is a SUM of cost of all operators preceding the one you are looking at. The easiest example is to look at the left-most icon - it will have an `Estimated sub tree cost` of whole query plan.
2. There are a lot of sign in a query plan that show it needs optimization, however, I've seen a lot of situations when even perfect plans caused troubles.
   At first you can look at following:

   - Estimated number of rows is far different from actual number of rows;
   - If you see thick lines (millions of records);
   - If you see spills in Tempdb;
   - If you see any red signs or exclamation points;
   - If you see Key Lookups
   - Many, many more...

All of these signs do not mean that plan is `bad`, but you have to look at them and make sure everything is OK.