# When Execution Plan Cost Differs From IOPs and Time

Tags: sql-server

Generally, the query execution plan's overall cost aligns with the statistical IOPs.  However, I've run into a situation where this isn't the case; one plan, which uses no throttling of CPU, shows it's less expensive by 6%, yet the more expensive plan (which uses `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)`) has significantly fewer reads and requires less time.  I tested the order of the query which came first and last and I continue to obtain the same results (even when running them independently).

> The no maxdop option query is 6% faster by query execution plan, but has significantly more reads and takes more seconds regardless of whether it is run first or last over the MAXDOP 1 query.

In a situation where the query execution plan shows that one plan is smaller than the other overall, but the statistics show a lot more reads on the more expensive one and it takes a lot less time, what's the best way to determine which is more effective?

**Update**

Just some numbers:

Plan one (no MAXDOP): 6% less cost by execution plan

Plan two `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)`: Per Stats IO, fewer scans, logical reads,WorkTables involved; less time by 2 seconds overall.

Comment: Plan cost is just a number. I would rely on statistics IO and time for any optimization that I do.

Comment: @Kin Thanks for the feedback; that's generally what I do since that measures what the numerical hits are.  Generally, these are similar (or very close like 50-50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server uses a cost based optimization model. The exact cost will depend on the row size and distribution info which will be context-sensitive and dynamic. Even in actual execution plans, the [cost figure is based on estimates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9983/8783).

From : [An Introduction to Cost Estimation](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/07/an-introduction-to-cost-estimation/)

> In recent versions of SQL Server this **cost should no longer be interpreted as seconds, milliseconds, or any other unit.**

Back to your question :

> what's the best way to determine which is more effective?

I *used* to rely on `statistics time and IO`. Any change I make e.g. create index, rewrite the query, use query hint, update / create statistics etc. I would measure the CPU time, reads and writes.

Since I purchased SQL Sentry's Plan Explorer PRO, I just use it to compare the before and after plans.

Also, you can get [Multiple Plans for an "Identical" Query](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/11/t-sql-queries/multiple-plans-identical-query) - check the SET options, any cAsE and whitespace or schema references as well.

Great references :

- [Inside the Optimizer: Plan Costing](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/09/01/inside-the-optimizer-plan-costing.aspx)
- [When is a Seek not a Seek?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/16/when-is-a-seek-not-a-seek.aspx)

Comment: So without the tool, the IOPS are more accurate.  With these queries the only difference is the `MAXDOP 1`.  Good info @Kin.